# pause and continue using setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

what i want to achieve is when you click this href `<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="pauser">pause/continue</a>` the timer pauses and continues when pressed again.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 10;
    var id = setInterval(function() {
       counter--;
       if(counter > 0) {
            var msg = 'You can continue ' + counter + ' seconds';
            $('#notice').text(msg);
       } else {
            $('#notice').hide();
            $('#download').show();
            clearInterval(id);
      }
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

My HTML in relevance to the jQuery is here if you need.

```
<a href="http://myurl.com" id="download" class="button" style="display: none;font-size:30px;">Continue !!</a><p id="notice">
You can continue in 10 seconds</p>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I would just have your pause event set a boolean, and then check that boolean before you decrement your counter:

```
<a href="javascript:setPause();" class="pauser">pause/continue</a>
```

and

```
var ispaused=false;
function setPause(){
   ispaused=!ispaused;
}
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var counter = 10;
var id = setInterval(function() {
   if(!ispaused){ ////the only new line I added from your example above
     counter--;
     if(counter > 0) {
          var msg = 'You can continue ' + counter + ' seconds';
          $('#notice').text(msg);
     } else {
          $('#notice').hide();
          $('#download').show();
          clearInterval(id);
    }
  }
}, 1000);
});
```

That should do it, right?

Comment: May as well just wrap the whole thing in that if instead of just the counter decrement.

Comment: If the counter does not decrement, things still happen. Better `return;` if `ispaused`.